# Select column value if not null else use another column value

Tags: mysql

I have 2 columns in mysql table: a and b. a is allways string value and b is sometimes a string value and sometimes it is null.

How to construct a mysql SELECT so that the b would be taken if it is not null and a would be taken otherwise.

I tried to make some magic with concat and if...then with no success...

UPDATE - To extend my question, is there a function that would work like Ifnull but would work for null AND empty values?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [IFNULL(b, a)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns expr2.

This is a MySQL specific function. You can also use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) in the same way. This will work in more databases but it has slightly worse performance in MySQL than IFNULL.

Comment: Sorry I didn't find this function mysqlf.

Answer (score 3):

[`IFNULL(b, a)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) ?

Answer (score 3):

```
IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
```

If expr1 is TRUE (expr1 <> 0 and expr1 <> NULL) then IF() returns expr2; otherwise it returns expr3.