# select a column if the other column already selected is null

Tags: mysql

```
DEV|MUL
xyz|null
null|abc
123|456
```

I want to get the value of a column where the other one is null or get specifically one column if both have values from mysql

Comment: Take a look @ 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952406/select-column-value-if-not-null-else-use-another-column-value

Use IFNULL(b, a).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IFNULL`

```
SELECT IFNULL(DEV, MUL) as Col FROM myTable  -- MySql

SELECT ISNULL(DEV, MUL) as Col FROM myTable  -- SQL Server

SELECT NVL(DEV, MUL) as Col FROM myTable  -- Oracle
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IFNULL(DEV, MUL) AS VALUE from table table1;
```

This will return `DEV` column value if it is `not null` otherwise return `MUL` column value.

Comment: i think its just trying out in the first col and returning the value in it

Comment: @freakk69  You sure you have value in the second column at the same time as shown in your example?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename where (columnname is null)
and
select * from tablename where (columnname1 is null) and (columnname2 is null)
```